# force a user login at first or when he want to pay?

Tags: android, authentication

I have a clothes shopping store **android app**, and I doubt which is better:

1. when **a user installed my app** force him to **login**?
2. Before Checkout?
   I want to know the benefits and disadvantages of each process

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: you really need to think about the flow of your app. maybe look up other apps and see how they do it. from the most part, they let you browse before creating an account...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to display the Login Page first with "SKIP" button for non-existing users, such that they see the items in your store first and then let the user make an account if he would like to.

Also, integrate non-login checkout feature for better user experience.